# aws_launch_configuration errors with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have slightly changed [An introduction to Terraform](https://blog.gruntwork.io/an-introduction-to-terraform-f17df9c6d180) code.
My goal is to deploy cluster of web servers
My code,main.tf

```
provider "aws" { region = "eu-central-1"}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "example" {
    ami = "ami-df8406b0"
    image_id      = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]

user_data = <<-EOF
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Hello, World" > index.html
   nohup busybox httpd -f -p "${var.server_port}" &
   EOF

lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
}   
}

variable "server_port" {
  description = "The port the server will use for HTTP requests"
  default = 8080
}


resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
 name = "terraform-example-instance"
 ingress {
   from_port = "${var.server_port}"
   to_port = "${var.server_port}"
   protocol = "tcp"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        }

lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
} 

}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}


resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
    launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.example.id}"
    min_size = 2
    max_size = 10

    tag {
        key = "Name"
        value = "terraform-asg-example"
        propagate_at_launch = true
    }
}
```

When I go for terraform plan

```
2 error(s) occurred:

* aws_launch_configuration.example: : invalid or unknown key: ami
* aws_launch_configuration.example: : invalid or unknown key: vpc_security_group_ids
```

I am a little bit confused with data,it serves for what?
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that you have specified two arguments to a `aws_launch_configuration` resource which aren't valid; namely `ami` and `vpc_security_group_ids`, see [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html) for what's valid.

I suspect you've changed from using a single `aws_instance` resource to an `aws_launch_configuration` resource, however they don't use the same arguments.

Comment: I have taken a look at documentatiom,still I do not understand how to specify my ami?Yes,that is true that I have changed from single instance.

Comment: The howto you linked to shows you how to do this. See the "Deploy a cluster of web servers" section and its first code section. You need to remove those two invalid arguments from the resource before Terraform will even try and create your infrastructure.

Comment: @MikiBelavista `aws_instance` takes `ami`, where `aws_launch_configuration` takes `image_id`. They are different, in large part because this functionality was added very early in the Terraform project, and done before they had much consistency between resource-types.